# convert JSP site to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jsp

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.  I have an existing site which was written in Java and has many JSP files (as well as many other file types).  I want to convert the site to ASP.NET.  I see that in the past there was a Java Language Conversion Assistance.  In further research it appears that the tool is built into Visual Studio.  However, I cannot find any documentation that steps me through how to run the Wizard.  Where can I find it in VS 2010?